# Fetch specific columns from Azure storage table query with the Javascript API

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Is it possible to fetch specific columns from an Azure storage table with the Javascript library.

Right now I can fetch the entire row, but I want just a few of the columns.

Here is what I'm doing to fetch the entire row from the table

```js
var tableUri = "https://mytablerg.table.core.windows.net";
var tableService = AzureStorage.Table.createTableServiceWithSas(tableUri, sasToken);
var tableQuery = new AzureStorage.Table.TableQuery().top(100).where('PartitionKey eq ?', partitionName);

tableService.queryEntities('ChatMessages', tableQuery, null, function(error, result, response) {
   // do some work with a returned data
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appending your original query with  method `select()` should work.

```
var tableQuery = new AzureStorage.Table.TableQuery().top(100).where('PartitionKey eq ?', partitionName).select('field1','field2');
```

Have a look at the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-nodejs?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json).

Comment: Thanks, do you know where I can find documentation for writing these queries in javascript? I can't find much....

Comment: @user1186050 Added in my answer.